# Possible use cases for std::ranges::empty_view<T>

Tags: c++

After looking at the specification for std::ranges::empty_view and std::ranges::views::empty, I can't think of a use case for a range that is always empty. The only example in the standard is to declare an empty_view and then static_assert that it's empty, which seems pointless to me. My question is what are some possible use cases for an empty_view?

Here's the pertinent cppreference page for reference

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/empty_view

and the latest working draft of the standard

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4878.pdf

Comment: Imagine you have a complicated templated routine with a bunch of input parameters and some of them are ranges that are being iterated. Suppose, in certain cases you don't want to use all the features. Do you duplicate the whole routine for this special case if you could simply pass an empty view?

Comment: The reasons are similar to "Why do we want 0?" and "Why is the identity function useful?"